# How to put the hr line on the specified position in div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
div.test{width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid red;}
```

The css will create a box with 100px width and 100px height .
How can draw a hr line which begins with  coordinate (0,50) ,ends with coordinate(100,50) in the div.test?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the coordination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can draw a hr line which begins with coordinate (0,50) ,ends with coordinate(100,50) in the div.test?

Use a pseudo element to draw the horizontal line absolutely positioned relative to the parent.

```css
div.test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.test::after {
  content: '';
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Position the `<hr>` accordingly.

```css
div.test{width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid red;}
hr {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  margin-top: -50px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<hr>
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you gave your hr a margin-top of 50%?

CSS

```
#line{
    margin-top:50%;
}
```

HTML

```
<hr id="line" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hr {
  margin-top: -50px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```